# Google Maps API for Business Quota

Tags: google-maps

My company purchased a Google Maps API for Business license, but there is a lot of confusion on the quota that we're allowed to use.
I want to use this license in a new project, but I need to convince that we are well under our limit.

Here is the license that we purchased:

> *GM-INT-250K-OEM   |   Google Maps API Premier: 12 month license/support term; up to 250,000 internal page views; Maps API for
>   Business - internal application; 250K annual pageviews*

It describes that we should get 250K **annual** page views. However, this doesn't make any sense because the "free" license gives 25K page views a **day**.

I apologize if this isn't the right place to ask this since it isn't a code issue. If anyone can confirm that the quota limit is indeed per day and not per year, that would be extremely helpful. If you can also refer to a link that clearly states this, that would be exactly what I need. For some reason, I haven't been able to find this :(

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems unlikely that your license has a mistake in it of that magnitude, but you should ask your Google sales rep if you want to confirm the numbers.

I can tell you why it doesn't seem to make sense, though: the 25K and 250K numbers aren't referring to the same thing.

The free Maps API license is for websites available to the general public at no charge, and Google is allowed to put advertising on your map.

You're not allowed to use the free license at all for an internal application.

So, the 250K annual views you get with the Business license is quite a bit more than the *zero* views you'd get with the free license. :-)

Also, here is a thought on minimizing your number of page views. Google counts the initial page view of a map only. Once the map page is loaded, you can keep interacting with it as long as you like without costing another page view.

So you'd want to avoid structuring your internal app with different pages that all load their own maps. Those would be individual page views. Instead, create a single-page app that loads the map once and keeps it loaded. You can even show and hide the map without costing another page view. Just don't reload the page. (And encourage your users to be economical by leaving your app loaded instead of reloading it all the time.)

Comment: The odd thing is that other license SKUs don't say "annual pageviews", they just say the number of total page views. I was hoping that someone with experience with this type of license could share his knowledge...